# How do i add a loading icon/ loader while my markers get loaded into the leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I am fetching data from an API, Data is in the Json Format and "datapoint" is the Json Object.
It takes quite some time to load around 300 markers, so i wanted to add a loader while these markers load and loader should go off as soon as all the markers gets loaded.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common approach is have some html like this:

```
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Then style it with CSS:

```
#loader {
    background: url(spinner.gif);
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

Then in your javascript function that makes the api call do the following:

```
$("#loader").show();
$.ajax( "http://apisite.com/apicall" ).done(function() {
    $("#loader").hide();
});
```

Your javascript call will probably look different but the core aspect is to show the spinner div before you do the ajax call and when the ajax call is done you hide it.